# 100th derivative of $\frac{1+x^2}{1+\tan^2(x)}$ at point 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}}\frac{1+x^2}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$
Without Taylor
Is there a way to solve this problem by using General Leibniz rule. I tried but numerator make problem.

Comment: $ t g = \tan $?

Comment: Yes, but I fix now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{1+\tan^2(x)}=(1+x^2)\cos^2 x=\frac12(1+x^2)\cos (2x)+\frac12(1+x^2)
$$ then one may apply the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)
$$
(uv)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} u^{(k)} v^{(n-k)}
$$
with $u(x)=1+x^2$ and $v(x)=\cos (2x)$, taking into account that $\displaystyle v^{(m)}(x)=2^m\cos \left(2x+\frac{m\pi}2\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

A better hint. Once you apply the first line of Olivier's hint, Taylor series for $\cos 2 x$ gives you the answer immediately.

Comment: I didn't give this path because the OP wrote "Without Taylor Is there a way to solve this problem..." :)

Comment: I like it anyway'

Comment: @OlivierOloa Ah, I did not read carefully - I had assumed the OP had difficulty expanding the original form in a series...